# Error while trying to get first and last of previous month from current date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0); -----First day of previous month
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1); ------Last Day of previous month
```

I'm getting a error as mentioned below when I run the above query to get the first and last day of previous month from current date.

> ERROR: Amazon Invalid operation: function
> pg_catalog.date_diff("unknown", integer, timestamp without time zone)
> does not exist; [SQL State=42883, DB Errorcode=500310]

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Test:

First day of previous month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE))
```

Last day of previous month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, -1, DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE))
```